# Program wont run.... Java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I need to make a program for my class that asks the user 3 different years and tells him/her if that said year is a leap year or not... this is my code (P.S we need to use loops to do this so keep it with loops):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class BetterLeapYear
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int year = s.nextInt();
        if (year > 1582){

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.print ("Please enter a year: ");
            year = s.nextInt();
        }

        if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)==0)) {
            System.out.print("That year was a leap year");
        }
        else if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)!=0)){
            System.out.println("This year was not a leap year");
        }
        else if ((year%4)== 0){
            System.out.print("This year was a leap year");
        }
        else 
            System.out.print("This year was not a leap year");
        }
        else 
           System.out.print ("Please enter a year after 1582");
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you fix your indentation, you'll see that all the code that checks the year is outside of your for loop. Try debugging it in Eclipse to see what it's actually doing!

Comment: Your implementation of leap year criteria is wrong. What is your question anyway?

Comment: I need someone to fix it... I don't really know how to "fix" my code... if you guys can make it work I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Also, there's two `else` clauses...

Comment: @DennisMeng think the last else clause is for the very first if statement. its just bad indentation.

Comment: @CodingBird Ah, yeah I see it now. Just another reason to have consistent style with braces :/

Comment: Fix your indentation and you'll be able to read your own code clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly let user enter a value for year. Then to check whether it is before year 1582 or not. and last check whether  it is a leap year or not.

Put code `year = s.nextInt();`  and `if (year < 1582) {` into for-loop to receive the year entered and to check whether the year entered is after 1582 or not.

These three steps are mentioned below:

Like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        /*
         * Step#1 Receive a year value 
         */
        System.out.println("Please enter a year: ");
        year = s.nextInt();

        /*
         * Step#2 Check if the year is after 1580 or not.
         * 
         */
        if (year < 1582) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a year after 1582");
        } else {
            /*
             * Step#3 Check whether the year entered is leap year or not 
             */
            if (((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100) == 0)
                    && ((year % 400) == 0)) {
                System.out.println("That year was a leap year");
            } else if (((year % 4) == 0) && ((year % 100) == 0)
                    && ((year % 400) != 0)) {
                System.out.println("This year was not a leap year");
            } else if ((year % 4) == 0) {
                System.out.println("This year was a leap year");
            } else
                System.out.println("This year was not a leap year");
        }
    }
```